# Sections from an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I am trying to recreate this codepen with react and gsap on here and i have been trying to recreate this for about an hour now and do not even know where to start from, please who can help. i do not want to create the sections the same way in that codepen but rather form the details from an array of objects meaning creating just once component, i am fairly new to react and i would like know how to do something like that in react, looking at it from vanillajs perspective, i already know what is going on and i also created it like this in react but i want a situation where i have minimal code and the an array of objects forms one component making it more dynamic so i can click on it to get more information about each section that comes in. kindly assist
Codepen link below
https://codepen.io/designsbyharp/pen/jObpWZg

HTML

```
<div class="slider">
  
  <div class="slider__slide slider__slide--1">
    <div class="slider__img slider__img--1"></div>
    <div class="slider__text slider__text--1">
      <h1 class="slider__header">Rejuvenate your, true self.</h1>
      <a href="ign.com" class="cta">discover</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slider__slide slider__slide--2">
    <div class="slider__img slider__img--2"></div>
    <div class="slider__text slider__text--2">
      <h1 class="slider__header">Professonial, trust-worthy, and compassionate.</h1>
      <a href="google.com" class="cta">learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="slider__slide slider__slide--3">
    <div class="slider__img slider__img--3"></div>
    <div class="slider__text slider__text--3">
      <h1 class="slider__header">Trust in us.</h1>
      <a href="youtube.com" class="cta">learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slider__slide slider__slide--4">
    <div class="slider__img slider__img--4"></div>
    <div class="slider__text slider__text--4">
      <h1 class="slider__header">What we do.</h1>
      <a href="tsn.ca" class="cta">discover</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slider__navigation">
    <div class="slider__count slider__count--top">
      <p class="count count--top count--top-1">01</p>
      <p class="count count--top count--top-2">02</p>
      <p class="count count--top count--top-3">03</p>      
      <p class="count count--top count--top-4">04</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slider__bar">
      <div id="sliderBarDynamic" class="slider__bar--dynamic"></div>
      <div class="slider__bar--static"></div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="slider__count slider__count--bottom">
      <p class="count count--bottom count--bottom-1">02</p>
      <p class="count count--bottom count--bottom-2">03</p>
      <p class="count count--bottom count--bottom-3">04</p>      
      <p class="count count--bottom count--bottom-3">01</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gilda+Display&family=Roboto&display=swap');

*,
*::before,
*::after{
padding:0;
margin:0;
box-sizing:inherit;
}

html{
font-size:16px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
color:#444444;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 1.6;
}

img{
max-width:100%;
}

h1{
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Gilda Display', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
}

h2{

}


h3{

}


P{
  color: #fff;
}

a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

ul{
list-style-type:none;
}



// Slider 
.slider{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  
  &__slide{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    
    &--1{
      z-index: 4;
    }
    
    &--2{
      z-index: 3;
    }
    
    &--3{
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    &--4{
      z-index: 1;
    }
  }
  
  &__img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    
    &--1{
      background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/Y0T3F1tc/about-landing.jpg');
    }
    
    &--2{
      background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/FHHyKWyf/i-Stock-1148043788.jpg');
    }
    
    &--3{
      background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/tTqp06QH/i-Stock-1064136816.jpg');
    }
    
    &--4{
      background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/435R13K2/i-Stock-1179976698.jpg');
    }
  }
  
  &__text{
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding: 0 0 5vw 15vh;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1005px;
    
    .slider__header{
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    
    .cta{
      font-weight: 700;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 6px;
      margin-left: 65px;
      position: relative;
      
      &:before{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        left: -55px;
        width: 40px;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: white;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Slider Navigation
  &__navigation{
    width: 21px;
    height: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: calc(100% - 5vw);
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .count--top{
    
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    
    // position:
  }
  
  .count{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .count:first-child{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .count--bottom{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  &__bar{
    width: 2px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    
    &--dynamic{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #FF69B4;
      transform-origin: top center;
      
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    &--static{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: darkgrey;
      
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  }
}
// Slider end
```

```
/*
*/

// timeline to control animations everytime the timeline restarts/repeats
let tlRepeat = gsap.timeline();

// Need first slides elements - img and text to animate on each repeat of timeline
let repeatBeginning = ()=>{
  gsap.set(bgImage[0], {opacity: 0, scale: 1.2, webkitFilter:"blur(" + 6 + "px)"})  

 tlRepeat
  .add("slide1-in")
  .fromTo([countTop[0], countBottom[0]], {opacity: 0}, {duration: 0.3, opacity: 1, ease: "Power2.easeIn"}, "slide1-in")  
  .to(bgImage[0], {duration: 1.8, scale: 1, opacity: 1, webkitFilter:"blur(" + 0 + "px)"}, "slide1-in")
  .fromTo(text[0], {opacity: 0, x: -30, ease: "Power2.easeIn"}, {duration: 0.8, opacity: 1, x: 0}, "-=1")


}

// On start animations
// let onStartSlide1Animations = ()=>{
//     // gsap.to(text[0], {duration: 0.7, opacity: 1, x: -15, ease: "Power2.easeIn"})
// }

// Variables
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__slide'),
    dynamicBar = document.querySelector('#sliderBarDynamic'),
    countTop = document.querySelectorAll(".count--top"),
    countBottom = document.querySelectorAll(".count--bottom"),
    bgImage = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__img"),
    text = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__text"),
    tl = gsap.timeline({repeat: 0, delay: 1, paused: false, onRepeat: repeatBeginning});
    
// Push all text back and only make first one visible
gsap.set(text, {x: -30});
gsap.set(text[0], {opacity: 1});


// Animate slide's elements but not the first one. 
// Make first slide's elements animate when timeline is repeating, 
// Follow the flow of rest of the slide's animations
slides.forEach((slide, i) =>{
  
  tl
    .fromTo(dynamicBar, {scaleY: 0}, {duration: 1.4, scaleY: 1}, "+=2")
    .set(dynamicBar, {transformOrigin: "bottom center"})
    .to(dynamicBar, {duration: 1, scaleY: 0}, "+=0.4")
    .set(dynamicBar, {transformOrigin: "top center"})
    .add("elements-in-out")
    .to([countTop[i], countBottom[i]], {opacity: 0}, "elements-in-out")  
    .to([countTop[i+1], countBottom[i+1]], {opacity: 1}, "elements-in-out")
    .to(bgImage[i], {duration: 0.2, opacity: 0}, "elements-in-out")
    .set(bgImage[i+1], {scale: 1.2, webkitFilter:"blur(" + 6 + "px)"}, "elements-in-out")
    .to(bgImage[i+1], {duration: 1.8, scale: 1, webkitFilter:"blur(" + 0 + "px)"}, "elements-in-out")
    .to(text[i], {duration: 0.3, opacity: 0}, "elements-in-out")
    .to(text[i+1], {duration: 0.8, opacity: 1, x: 0}, "-=1")
})
```

Comment: Are you asking how to move/convert the "HTML" markup into an array that is mapped to JSX? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes that's is what I am asking for, but my method keeps on sitting on each other and nothing works, frustrated with it.

Comment: Can you clarify what "my method keeps on sitting on each other and nothing works" means? Can you add a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt to convert the static HTML to generated JSX in your question?

Comment: Okay let me share what exactly i am doing,
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-greider-7xgkdm
this is an example by cassie but I want to produce it in a react way
i have a data.js file which is an array of objects but now instead of the traditional having to manually input all sections i want to have one component that does that and upon scroll it changes making it more dynamic, lets say i want to click on a component and i want the data of a particular section as a modal or a page that is where i am getting confused, already removed everything i have tried since

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you want a more DRY implementation so the slides are not explicitly written out in HTML/JSX.

Gather up the values that are different between each slide, i.e. the heading and image sources, into an array that can be mapped in the return.

Example:

```
const slides = [
  {
    id: 0,
    heading: "SCROLL",
    image: {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567016376408-0226e4d0c1ea?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0NjMyMDUzOA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=400",
      alt: ""
    },
    overlay: {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519710164239-da123dc03ef4?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0NjMxOTU4Mw&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=800",
      alt: ""
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    heading: "SWIPE",
    image: {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558603668-6570496b66f8?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0NjMyMDUzOA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&w=400",
      alt: ""
    },
    overlay: {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594666757003-3ee20de41568?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0NjMxOTcwOA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=800",
      alt: ""
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    heading: "SCROLL",
    image: {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537165924986-cc3568f5d454?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0NjMyMDU4NA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&w=400",
      alt: ""
    },
    overlay: {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579830341096-05f2f31b8259?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0NjMxOTQ5Ng&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=800",
      alt: ""
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    heading: "SWIPE",
    image: {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589271243958-d61e12b61b97?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0NjMyMDU4NA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=400",
      alt: ""
    },
    overlay: {
      src:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603771628302-c32c88e568e3?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0NjMxOTUxNg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=800",
      alt: ""
    }
  }
];
```

Replace the repetitive JSX for mapping this `slides` array.

```
{slides.map((slide) => (
  <section key={slide.id} class="slide">
    <div class="slide__outer">
      <div class="slide__inner">
        <div class="slide__content">
          <div class="slide__container">
            <h2 class="slide__heading">{slide.heading}</h2>
            <figure class="slide__img-cont">
              <img
                class="slide__img"
                alt={slide.image.alt}
                src={slide.image.src}
              />
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
))}

<section class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay__content">
    <p class="overlay__count">
      0<span className="count">1</span>
    </p>
    <figure class="overlay__img-cont">
      {slides.map((slide) => (
        <img
          key={slide.id}
          class="image"
          src={slide.overlay.src}
          alt={slide.overlay.alt}
        />
      ))}
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: Edit sections-from-an-array-of-objects]

Comment: Wow, exactly thanks, Jeez looking at your implementation makes me see how stupid I am, you are a live saver.what if I wanted to implement this to my first example, how would I go about that?

Comment: what if I wanted to implement this to my first example, how would I go about that?

Comment: @Ayodele I think the process would be the same, figure out what is different for each slide you want to display and place that into an array so you can iterate over it to render into the "common" part.